# Windows phone 7 web browser control user agent

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

The present user agent for the browser control that i see in the emulator is `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; Microsoft; XDeviceEmulator)` and i want to change that to `Mozilla/5.0 Windows NT 6.1 AppleWebKit/535.1 KHTML, like Gecko Chrome/14.0.835.187 Safari/535.1` or something similar.

How to code that in C# to change the user agent string for the web browser control.

Comment: For Windows Phone The `Navigate` parameter wont accept more than one argument. You will get "No overload for method 'Navigate' takes 4 arguments" error. There is a similar question and answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943812/webbrowser-navigate-user-agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943812/webbrowser-navigate-user-agent)

Comment: Windows Phone has a [WebBrowser.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626636(v=vs.92).aspx) method with 3 parameters, that allows you to send the HTTP Headers you want on the request!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this wasn't the case when i originally responded to this question. Do I delete my answer for fear of losing all my rep pts or update it with the new details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way `webBrowser.Navigate("http://localhost/run.php", null, "User-Agent: Here Put The User Agent");`

Comment: @Jeyant: really very helpful information. I am opening webbrowser inside my app and want to modify useragent in each request. Is it possible?

Comment: If you go on google it will show in desktop view, but when you click on the page and the browser navigates, it will go back to mobile view.

Comment: what about cookie ? is it possible to add cookie like this ? how ?please give me a replay ..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 7.5, there is a Navigate method overload that allows setting the headers.  There are 3 arguments ( URI, post_info, header_info) , not 4 as shown.

The overload worked for me.

Good luck.
-e

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found an unbelievably simple answer, and that worked.

All you need do is to edit the Web Browser Control XAML. Add the property IsScriptEnabled="True"

Hope this solutions helps.

Comment: Does this answer the question? They were asking to change the User Agent string. This answer appears to enable script support.

Comment: I was facing the same issue while navigating any website from browser control and that didn't detected that app is from mobile browser [doesn't detect user agent] and using the solution I posted above, it worked for me without explicitly specifying user agent in webbrowser.navigate method. and that's why I've posted as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would be something like this, in vb:

WebBrowser.Navigate(New Uri("URL"), byteArr, HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent & ":" & "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; fr-fr; HTC Desire Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1")

However, I cannot modify the headers already appended to the request, you can only add them, which I find pretty annoying.

Anyone have succeeded in doing this??