# modify userAgent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, browser, user-agent

is it possible to modify the userAgent using JavaScript?
I personally only know the getter window.navigator.userAgent, but this won't help me.

Comment: The HTTP header? No, you cannot modify the (request) headers using JavaScript. `navgiator.userAgent`? Only by using a trick.

Comment: Are you using the WebBrowser control, can you use it in the Navigate method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631740/windows-phone-7-web-browser-control-user-agent

Comment: the wp7 webbrowser control is a little bit different i think, there is no standard-solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function(){
    return 'foo' // customized user agent
});

navigator.userAgent; // 'foo'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Or `Object.defineProperty(navigator,'userAgent', {value:'foo'});`

Comment: the last line is just the proof, isn't it? I'll try this.

Comment: Yup, just to make sure.  I haven't tested in all browsers.